# APT How to process annotations of nested annotated classes

Tags: java, annotations, nested, apt, annotation-processing

I am trying to write an annotation processor using java.  This annotation processor needs to identify annotated nested classes within an annotated class as seen below.  I will process the annotated classes first then process their inner annotations.  This is performed at compile time and I will have no existing knowledge of the class being processed.  It is possible to have multiple nested classes within Foo.  How do I process the annotations of all these nested classes.

```
@MyAnnotation(value="Something important")
public class Foo
{
    private Integer A;

    @MyMethodAnnotation(value="Something Else")
    public Integer getA() { return this.A; }

    @MyAnnotation(value="Something really important")
    private class Bar
    {
        private Integer B;

        @MyMethodAnnotation(value="Something Else that is very Important")
        public Integer getB() { return this.B }     
    }
}
```

How can I get access to the nested Bar class, it's annotation 'MyAnnotation' and its 'MyMethodAnnotation' during processing?  The following code only prints out information about class Foo.  How can I process information about Bar?

```
for (Element element : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)) {
    if ( element.getKind().equals(ElementKind.CLASS) )
    {
        System.out.println(element.getKind().name() + " " + element.getSimpleName() );
        processInnerClassElement(element);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(element.getKind().name() + " " + element.getSimpleName() );
    }    
}

...


private void processInnerClassElement(Element element)
{
    for (Element e : element.getEnclosedElements() )
    {
        if ( e.getKind().equals(ElementKind.CLASS) )
        {
            System.out.println(e.getKind().name() + " " + e.getSimpleName() );
            processInnerClassElement(e);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(e.getKind().name() + " " + e.getSimpleName()  );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try accessing an element on the nested class Bar using 
    for ( Element e : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(EmfInfo.class) )
    {

but this only returns the outer most class Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends how these annotation relate to each other.

You could simply declare all the annotations in @SupportedAnnotationTypes and have several blocks in the process-method like:

```
for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)) {
    MyAnnotation myAnnotation = element.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
    if (myAnnotation != null) {
        doSomething(myAnnotation, element);
    }
}

for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyMethodAnnotation.class)) {
    MyMethodAnnotation myMethodAnnotation = element.getAnnotation(MyMethodAnnotation.class);
    if (myMethodAnnotation != null) {
        doSomething(myMethodAnnotation, element);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you might be able to use `element.getEnclosedElements()` and `element.getEnclosingElement()` to achieve what you want.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I actually had a problem in my source that was causing me errors. With that corrected the solution above processed the annotations of the nested class.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a few methods from [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) to do this, specifically to get the classes declared in `Foo`, the annotations on those classes, the methods declared in those classes, and the annotations on those methods. Here is a quick example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (Class<?> declaredClass : Foo.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = declaredClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        // Process value of class annotation here
        for (Method method : declaredClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            MyMethodAnnotation myMethodAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(MyMethodAnnotation.class);
            // Process value of method annotation here
        }
    }
}
```

It might be insightful to read through the documentation about reflection in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: You are speaking about reflection API. OP asked about annotation processor. It is not reflection. It is other API that is a kind of extension to java compiler.

Comment: I am using the Annotation Processing Tool an extension of the complier in Java6.  I do not know the nested class names while I am processing files using the Annotation Processing Tool at compile time.